# Unable to add ubuntu to windows domains? using centrify

Tags: windows, active-directory

I'm using this [guide](http://www.question-defense.com/2012/08/31/dpkg-error-processing-likewise-open-configure-join-linux-server-to-windows-domain-controller) to add my linux (10.04 lucid) ubuntu machine to domain.

First I tried using likewise, but couldn't do this apparently due to some compatibility issues with 10.04 kernel. I had downloaded the 25 Mb size centrify agent. I run the command using this command: `./install-express.sh` Everything works fine. As i stumble on these sets of input

```
Active Directory domain to join  : example.com
Active Directory authorized user : administrator
computer name                    : dev
container DN                     : Computers
domain controller name           : domain-controller.example.com
```

In container DN name i have found a vbscript on the internet which allows me to retrieve given user name DN. E.G.: DN: CN=George Jetson, OU=Vehicles, OU=Engineering, DC=YOURDOAMIN,DC=COM

I enter Vehicles since this is the most specific of the OU definition. I'm doing this fine? Or i need to add like Vehicles.Engineering. ? Do i have to goto node level or just parent-node or sub-parent node.

However, as I enter the domain user/password and I accept Y at the end. It goes through couple of checks it says (PASS) to all of them until i'm echohed with the error. Its related to krb5 or some kind of authentication. This error is also seen in `var/log/centrify.log` with error code 26. This is not an authentication error because I have tried it with giving wrong credentials and the output given then is of incorrect user/password.

I want to know if I need to add some other packages of kerberos. Since I'm using backtrack 5 its not what you call a standard/Off the shelf ubuntu installation. Its most customized and built for security products integration.